# Does Audio Units support airplay？

Tags: ios, audio, airplay

I want to play music when airplay mirroring is connected, but is seems impossible to do that, when airplay mirroring is connected I can't force audio out to speaker, because airplay mirroring will disconnected when I do that. I want to know whether audio unit is support airplay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does. I have an app that uses a low-level custom Audio Unit and I just tested it on my Apple TV and it works fine with both mirroring and selecting the Apple TV device from the MPVolumeView view.

Comment: Thank you！ your answer help me a lot

Comment: You have to be aware that there might be a time delay between the audio being sent and the audio being played. When mirroring I've experienced it to be about 100ms. When streaming to AirPlay it's always 2s exactly.

Comment: sorry，I doesn't make the question clear, I want to play sound to the iphone speaker and connected airplay mirring server at the same time. when I use the code   success = [session overrideOutputAudioPort:AVAudioSessionPortOverrideSpeaker
                                          error:&error]; ,then the airplay is disconnected immediately

Comment: you're saying you want to play over the iphone speaker while mirroring using airplay?

Comment: i'm believe the override method you call is inteded for apps like skype which want to emulate a "speaker" button. i don't think it's possible to do what you're trying to accomplish.